# I have the same sql server version, try to restore db, got error: Specified cast is not valid. (SqlManagerUI)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, restore, database-restore

I have a customer which send me he's database. I have unzip it and try to restore it to my sql database. He is using SQL Server 2008 R2 and me to. I try the following steps:

1. open SQL Server Management Studio
2. login
3. right click on the databases folder
4. click on "Restore Database..."
5. I give the database a new name because I don't have it yet
6. I select the radio button "From device"
7. I browse and select the `.bak` file
8. I click on the OK button to start the restore

Now I got this error below. I don't understand what the problem is!

> Specified cast is not valid. (SqlManagerUI)
>
> Program Location:
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreDatabaseGeneral.PopulateGridWithBackupSetsFromDevices()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreDatabaseGeneral.GetBackupSetsFromDevices()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreDatabaseGeneral.textDeviceSelected_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Text(String value)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.set_Text(String value)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.set_Text(String value)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreDatabaseGeneral.buttonSelectDevice_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Answer (score 1):

Really weird problem, I was facing the same; and solved this way:

1. Detached database
2. Copy .MDF/.LDF (data and log) files for this database from appropriate location.
3. Rename copies and Paste it (same location if on same machine else in
   data location)
4. Attach it as new database.

Answer (score 0):

This usually can happen if the `.BAK` file is corrupted, check if the `.BAK` file is corrupted, you can also try to restore using the command

```
RESTORE DATABASE test FROM DISK = 'E:\test.bak'
```